# Error while compiling the code

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I got a error message while compiling, saying that

```
node.h: In member function ‘void binary_tree::print(node*&, std::ofstream&)’:
node.h:17:10: error: ‘node* node::left_child’ is private
```

But in node.h, the member is public

```
class node {
  public:
    char *word;         
    int frequency;
    node  *left_child;              
    node *right_child; };
```

using MinGW for build and run. Pls help me in solving this issue.

Comment: What has this error to do with 'make' in particular? It's a compiler error and hard to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing the code it actually complains about.

Comment: Your class definition needs a trailing `;`. The error does not correspond to the code you are showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to submit complete code for comments.

1. Error cannot occur if left_child is public. You can clean and rebuild your code.
2. binary_tree how is this class using class node?

Comment: here is my whole project file... http://is.gd/EjSCBb

Comment: @nwytAnon check these files https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1xNtnsgZBdpeUlVQ3FBSHc0WG8&usp=sharing

Comment: look for comments with "Nik:", I have added my comments, your code should compile now.

Answer (score 0):

it just worked well!!! but some kinda build error takes here. And this is the altered codes here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PwxyqEos-wb05vRzhvN21aYTQ/edit?usp=sharing